# How to solve problem with 2items with the same key?

Tags: reactjs

I usually using uuid from react-uuid but this time I get all time an error even I try to combine it with unique item.id..

```
     <Swiper
      {...params}
      >
            {listMovie?.map((item, index) =>{
const time = new Date(item.release_date)
             return(
              <React.Fragment key={`${item.id + uuid()}`}>
                 <SwiperSlide >
              <Grid  item className="items">
                <Card sx={{ maxWidth: "350" }}>
                  <div className="favorite">
                  <IconContext.Provider
      value={{ color: 'red', size: '30px' }}
    >
      <div className="fav" onClick={() => FavHanlder(item, index)}>
      {likes.includes(item.id) ?  <MdFavorite/> : <MdFavoriteBorder/>}
        </div>
        </IconContext.Provider>                  </div>
                  <Link to={`/movie/${item.id}`}>
                    <CardMedia
                      component="img"
                      height="350"
                      image={`${apiConfig.w500Image(item.poster_path)}`}
                    //   alt={item.Title}
                    />
                    <CardContent>
                
                    </CardContent>
                  </Link>
                </Card>
                <div className="title">     
                 <Typography variant="body2" color="white" >
                        {item.original_title}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography variant="body2" color="white" >
                        ({time?.getFullYear()})
                      </Typography>
                      <div style={{display: "flex", float: "left", paddingLeft: "10px", paddingRight: "10px"}}>
                      <ReactStars
    count={10}
    value={item.vote_average}

    size={10}
    isHalf={true}
    emptyIcon={<i className="far fa-star"></i>}
    halfIcon={<i className="fa fa-star-half-alt"></i>}
    fullIcon={<i className="fa fa-star"></i>}
    activeColor="#ffd700"
  /><p style={{fontSize: "5px"}}>/{item.vote_count}votes</p></div>
</div>
              </Grid>
              </SwiperSlide>
              </React.Fragment>
            )})}
            </Swiper>
```

I am a little bit confused, because this is an error of beginners.

full msg:

Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `.0`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Comment: check once "uuid()" in console.log. maybe its not work so the same key was rendered.

Comment: checked, work fine.